# Firefox recently updated to 89.0 (64 bit) and now sometimes locks up

Tags: 20.04, firefox

As the title says.  I sometimes have two windows open, one playing videos on youtube and another where I am doing other things.  And then it locks up.  I can't do anything, the x button won't close it, the mouse can move around but that's about it.  Eventually Ubuntu asks me if I want to wait or force close, so I force close.

Anyone else had this issue or know what is causing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can see what is going on behind the scenes in Firefox by accessing the Firefox Task Manager

This can be done simply and quickly by typing `about:performance` in the address bar

[image]

Once there you can see what the resource usage is, expand tabs to see trackers and to close tabs as required to identify any issues.

[image]

The Task Manager will allow you to identify rogue scripts and take appropriate action in identying any issues.

[reference](https://itsfoss.com/firefox-task-manager/)

If necessary, Firefox can be opened in safe mode: in terminal `firefox -safe-mode` but first make sure to close any Firefox instance before running this command.

Comment: I can't access firefox task manager as the whole thing has locked up.